# can we change the font color of Functions and variables in Matlab editor

Tags: matlab

Currently in MatLab 2012a the color of user variables e.g. rhoc, qin, qout etc. and reserved Functions e.g. imagesc, Figure, xlabel, caxis etc. IS the same i.e. BLACK, would be nice if I can change it - I am a new learner and it would be SO nice if I can differentiate them.  Please help - perhaps this is easy for you. Please answer ASAP. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't belive this is possible. One option is to use an alternative text editor with more comprehensive syntax highlighting, for example [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2).

Comment: Chris Taylor is right, the syntax highlighting options only have a different color for MATLAB keywords, but not all MATLAB functions.  Probably because code would end up looking like fruit salad.

Comment: I confirm that this is not possible, though it would be nice to have some kind of warning when overloading functions with user-defined variable names.

Comment: There is no such thing like "reserved" functions in MATLAB - you can override all matlab functions with either your own function or with some variable.

Answer (score 1):

Such a syntax highlighting is impossible. You could names variables identical to a build in function. Simple example:

```
eval(char([105   109    97   103   101   115    99   114    61    49    50]))
imagescr
```

In this case, execution of the code is necessary to realise that imagescr is "12".

Comment: Ooop sorry Daniel - but my mistake, I could not move them to Chris' thread. My apology, and thanks for your reply. I just deleted them then.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on my comment above - I use Sublime Text 2 as my code editor, which looks a bit like this.

Notice that all Matlab keywords (`for`, `if` and `end`) and built-in functions (`fprintf`, `datestr`) are highlighted in red. Strings are in yellow, and numeric literals and format specifiers within strings are in purple.

User-defined variables (`businessDate`, `t`, `T`, `binnedData`) appear in white and comments are in gray.

[image]

Comment: Who's telling sublime to highlight the builtin functions (is it a MATLAB mode or a selfmade list of keywords to highlight)? In this example, I'd find it very confusing to have `datestr` and `fprintf` highlighted identical to real keywords...

Comment: It's Sublime's MATLAB mode - although it it fully customisable, so you can add or remove keywords as you wish. You can also set different groupings of keywords to appear in different colors if you want to (for example, notice how `waitbar`, which is a command that creates GUI elements, appears in pale blue instead of red). I like to have built-in functions appearing distinct from user-created functions and variables, as it's a reminder of when I'm about to accidentally over-write a builtin with my own definition.

Comment: Yes, Chris I agree with you, but how do you add these different groupings in Matlab mode of Sublime 3 ? Can you please give me more clues

Comment: You can add/edit/remove keywords in the Sublime Text language config file for Matlab, which is normally called "Matlab.tmLanguage". On my system that is in "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\Matlab" but I'm afraid I can't tell you where it is on your system.

Comment: Yup I found dir C:\Users\mrbean_64\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages  ... but no subdir MatLab after Packages only subdir User and no files called Matlab.tmLanguage - any more hints ?

Comment: Would you be so kind to send me the file ? - I can try to put it in Matlab.tmLanguage

Comment: @user2931185 If you give me somewhere to send it to.

Comment: helloo Chris, please send the file Matlab.tmLanguage which will recognize MatLab functions in sublime, thank you

Comment: Oh thanks Chris, gee sublime 2 setting is different to sublime 3 ? I am still unable to change the color of say built in function Figure, do you have a suggestion ?

Comment: Please help Chris -  I still could not diplay different colors for built in MatLab functions in Sublime 2 - really appreciate your help